# Google DataFlow API for ingesting HLL_COUNT.INIT into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am sending data to PubSub from where I am trying to create a DataFlow job to put data into BigQuery.
I have a column in the data for unique that I want to do HLL_COUNT.INIT
Is there an equivalent method on the DataFlow side so that I can directly store the HLL version of the column in BigQuery?

Comment: I have the same use case with spark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, DataFlow doesn't have support for BigQuery HLL sketches format, but it is clearly something that would be useful. I created feature request for it in DataFlow issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/62153424.

**Update**: A BigQuery-compatible implementation of HyperLogLog++ has been open-sourced to github.com/google/zetasketch, and a design doc (docs.google.com/document/d/…) about integrating it into Apache Beam has been sent out to dev@beam.apache.org.

Comment: It would be great if you open sourced the solution. We want to use this with Apache Spark also.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/extensions/sketching

Comment: Update: A BigQuery-compatible implementation of HyperLogLog++ has been open-sourced to https://github.com/google/zetasketch, and a design doc (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U5aXdC9lDSOqT6FPHRulp-EutYiQ9KeHpgu-19CIfEI) about integrating it into Apache Beam has been sent out to dev@beam.apache.org.